# How to delay loop in for loop till notified in Swift?

Tags: swift

I need to perform several time consuming operations. Each one includes large mathematical calculations and GMS objects creation and takes 10s aprox. It uses notifications at several places.

I have parameters for each operation in a dictionary and I tried to use simple for loop to perform operations one by one but calculations are not sequenced properly. The number of calculations may differ so I need some loop to go through the dictionary.

I am thinking about waiting in loop until notified to perform next loop. I know where to post notification but cant find any solution how to observe it in a for loop. Is it correct approach and if so how to do it?

Any suggestions?

Edit1:
Example:

```
For calculation in calculationsDict {
       performCalculation(calc: calculation) // runs 10s in different threads
}
```

How to delay second and any subsequent performCalculation to the moment where each performCalculation is completely finished?

Edit2:
performCalculation has nested functions, it sends notifications to initiate other actions, and all actions together have hundreds lines of code and at the end there are many objects in the mapview as a result. What I need is to repeat that whole bunch of actions(here referred to as performCalcultion()) but just right when the previous one is completed completely.

Edit3:
What I ask for is how to make one performCalculation() having completion handler for next performCalculation().

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking so maybe you can clarify your question some, perhaps with some example code. Maybe you could create an array of your operations or use Combine, hard to give any solid advice without more information

Comment: Indeed, it’s not clear how you intend to use the nested loop. Can you provide some code?

Comment: The code is so complex that I am aware that my question is rather general. I am able to get desired result when doing performCalcultion() one by one and thats what I do at the beginning. All inputs are sorted and I save them to a json. If I need to replicate all desired results I load parameters from json and then I need to put those calculations to a queue but they are all dependent on the previous one so I need to start the new one after previous one is done.

Answer (score 0):

Your `performCalculation(calc:)` method definitely needs a completion closure parameter for us to know when the calculations for a given input are done. Let's say it now looks like this and you execute the completion when all of your inner asynchronous tasks are finished:

```swift
func performCalculation(calc: ..., completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // Call when all done
    completion()
}
```

I would then suggest implementing a method that will recursively call itself and pass the needed dict to the method above:

```swift
func performAllCalculations(with calculationsDict: ...) {
    guard calculationsDict.count > 0, let calculation = calculationsDict.first else {
        // Terminate recursion when the dict is empty
        return
    }
    // Calculate with the first item from the dict
    performCalculation(calc: calculation) { [weak self] in
        // Calculation is done
        // Call the main method again without the first item in the dict
        self?.performAllCalculations(with: calculationsDict.dropFirst())
    }
}
```

Comment: I used edit to add my comment ISO comment here, sorry for that.

Comment: I implemented your code and the problem is that performCalculation has inner function that sends a notification to start another functions and the completion of performCalculation is called before all those actions finish. Which takes me back to my idea how to wait in the performCalculation for some notification before calling completion()..